# PayPal proof of payment - is there a need to store it at our server?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, payment

I am developing an iPhone app, which I am integrating with PayPal.

I did it successfully using PayPal library. I am testing it on sandbox mode. When I transfer money from one account to the other account, it displays a message "send to server for verification".

Is there a real need to store this PayPal transaction id and other details on our server?

Answer (score 1):

While Apple will provide the user with their transaction (payment) history, your program will need to know when a user has paid, in order to make decisions such as allowing them access, or renewing their subscription (if it isn't one-time).

However, I don't know enough about iPhone API to know whether you should store the PayPal information yourself, or make calls to the API in order to make the above decisions.

Comment: are you sure apple will store information even if i do transaction with PayPal ?

Comment: I might have misunderstood.  When I said "Apple will provide the user with their transaction (payment) history" I was thinking of payments the user makes through Apple (like to pay for an app).  If that isn't the case, could you explain more what is happening?

Comment: I am doing integration with PayPal. So when transaction completes they return transaction receipt. I was talking about that receipt(Proof of payment).